# Error handling prepared statements in a production environment

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

In a production environment when using prepared statements and all other validation is done, do I need to error check every every step of the way or can I just check end result of `$stmt` for true or false?

I am trying to clean up about 2000 lines of a function file and a lot of it just seems like wasted space when there is so much validation already done(ie checking for empty values, required values, empty fields etc).

Here is a rough, extremely simple, example of what I would like to do.

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM foo WHERE somecol = ?";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s",$value);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($c);
$stmt->fetch();

if(false === $stmt){
    //My error report
    trigger_error("Something bad happened!" );
    //Error user sees
    $userErrorMsg[] 'Some generic msg here';
}
```

**EDIT:** I probably should have mention the `$conn` has been checked previously.

Comment: For a better user experience you should do all the checks and show relevant error messages to the user. A generic message will confuse the user and will be hard to him to understand what happened when sent the form.

Comment: A Generic msg would be "there was a db error, please try again", other than that I don't think they need anything relevant to why the query failed, any errors that could have been caused by the end user have been previously dealt with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decide if it's necessary in your case or not. But some programmers would say, that the code to catch an error is almost that much like the normal code.

**In short:** If there can be an error *CATCH IT* ;)

Otherwise I would recommend you to create a Wrapper class for your DB functions.

Just a small example to point you in the right direction:

```
class MyDBClass {
    private static $con = null;
    private static $instance = null;

    public static function getInstance() {
        if( null === self::$instance) {
            // add error handling ;)
            self::$instance = new MyDBClass();
            self::$instance->setConnection();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    private function setConnection() {
        if( null === self::$con) {
            // add error handling ;)
            self::$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
        }
    }

    private function __construct() {}

    public function select( $tableName, $columns = "*", $conditions = array(), $numRows = null ) {
        // add your stuff with error handling
    }

    public function selectRow( $tableName, $columns = "*" , $conditions = array() ) {
        // add your stuff with error handling
    }
}

// use of class
$db = MyDBClass::getInstance();
$db->select( "mytable" );// would (for example) select * from mytable
```

**NOTE:** This is not a working example and I would recommend to get use a good framework or a small wrapper class

Comment: This is definitely in the works for the next edit.I have been rolling it around in the noggin for a couple weeks, but time constraints are an issue at this point and my skills are not advanced enough yet to get this done in a timely manner. With that said, the error handling class I have just finished will let me know if literally anything goes wrong, even if the server burps at 2am after to many beers....lol So I think I am safe for the time being but something similar to this is at the top of the list for the next edit.

Comment: Glad to hear and think about "you don't have to reinvent the wheel" there are a lot of good,small and well maintained  wrapper classes on github ;)

Comment: This is true, however, for me, just using something never teaches me how to write and debug  it if I need to, so while I will use them as reference I will still probably write my own. If for no other than the need to learn.